# 5/9 is not taking by the C compiler to Calculate fc

Tags: c

I'm stuck in a Code where I have to convert a temperature given by the user (in Fahrenheit) to degree Celsius. But unfortunately it's formula is not working with C Compiler.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void c_f();
//void f_c();
float c,f,fc,fc1;

int main()
{
    c_f();
    //  f_c();

return 0;
getch();
}
void c_f()
{
    printf("\n Enter the temperature (in *F) to covert it into Celsius: ");
    scanf("%d",&f);

    fc=((5/9)*(f-32));
    printf("\n %f*C",fc);

}
```

Comment: add decimal portions to make it floating point.  5.0/9.0

Comment: You are doing integer division. `5/9 == 0 == true`

Comment: [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3602827/995714)

Comment: Besides the scanf issue, the most minimal change would be to just  add one `.`. Change `5/9` to be `5./9` or `5/9.`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct format specifier which will be `scanf("%f",&f)` in this case.

Also `fc=((5.0/9.0)*(f-32))`, otherwise integer division yields `0`.(*Integer division truncates*).`5/9.0` will also work.

It is useless to put `getch()` after `return` statement. It will never reach upto that line.

---

#### What happens in your version?

Actually when two integers are divided the result is the quotient. If there any fractional part it is discarded. If you divide 5 by 9 the result will be `0.555...`. When fractional part discarded it will be `0`. So you always get `0`.

Whenever you need an outcome of a division not t truncate you must make one of them floating point. That ensures that it(result) will *not* truncate.

---

So the program would be

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void celciusToFahreinheit();

float fahr_temp,celc_temp;

int main()
{
    celciusToFahreinheit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void celciusToFahreinheit() 
{
    printf("\n Enter the temperature (in *F) to covert it into Celsius: ");
    if( scanf("%f",&fahr_temp) != 1 ){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error in input\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    celc_temp=((5.0/9.0)*(fahr_temp-32));
    printf("\n %f*C",celc_temp);
}
```

Apart from the problem few things would be - Using readable function name and checking the return value of `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

```
fc=((5/9)*(f-32));
```

Because 5 and 9 are **integers**, the arithmetic calculation is done at integer level, thus `5/9 == 0`.

You should change it to floating point:

```
fc = ((5.0f / 9.0f) * (f - 32.0f));
```

Besides, format specifier `%d` is used for **integers**. If you want to read a floating point number, use `%f`:

```
scanf("%f", &f);
```

The result should be right now.